# pip install failing with no error on private pypi and normal pypi

Tags: python, pip, python-3.4

with and without a pip.ini file my pip install is failing. when running an individual pip install with -vvv I get this as the trace output, the output is the same when trying to pip install -r req.txt. for the individual install I removed the lib version to test and nothing

```
Collecting absl-py
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/absl-py/
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
```

I'm using python 3.4 and pip 7.1.2

does anyone know why this would be failing ?

Edit: i know both are out of date but this is legacy code thats in maintenance so cant be updated but has a bug that needs fixing

Edit2: i have managed to upgrade pip to 19.1 but the issue still persists. i can install packages outside the venv so assume its not a connectivity issue

Comment: Try to update your PIP. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: That doesn't look like an error. Are you sure it's not just taking a while to complete?

Comment: "I'm using python 3.4 and pip 7.1.2" Note that both are seriously outdated. Python 3.4 is no longer supported since over 3 years, and pip 7.1.2 is almost 7 years old.

Comment: @ex4 upgrading pip has the same outcome

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this doesnt complete it displays the above then stops and goes back to the terminal for input its like it doesnt complete

Comment: It actually sounds like a connectivity problem, there are more options like downloading the .whl and installing it although it´s an emergency solution, maybe try curl -LO ULR_of_pip_package and install it with wheel